# Javascript var returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable inside of a function:

```
var System = {
    startApp:function(package) {
        System.startApp.PACKAGE = package;
        System.startApp.PATH = "@APP:/" + package;
    },
};
```

But when i call the function:

```
var a = new System.startApp("Mr. T.");
alert(a.PACKAGE + ", " + a.PATH);
```

it returns a alert with the string `undrfined, undefined`.

The problem isn't the folder, i made using `mkdir` shell command.

This is not an application, this is an web page.

Question:

I need to call the function at the same mode in the `code above (2)`, but the function need to works. But how?

PS: nothing of APIs!

Comment: Not a constructor - can't use `new`.

Comment: I try to remove the new, but, the function doesn't show nothing

Comment: @JackBashford You *can* use `new` here - it's a full `function`, not an arrow function or a shorthand method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `startApp` function assigns to *the constructor* (the `startApp` function) - it's a property of the class, not a property of an instance. If you want to check the `PACKAGE` and `PATH`, check the properties of the constructor (either `a.constructor` or `System.startApp`):

```js
var System = {
    startApp:function(package) {
        System.startApp.PACKAGE = package;
        System.startApp.PATH = "@APP:/" + package;
    },
};
var a = new System.startApp("Mr. T.");
console.log(a.constructor.PACKAGE + ", " + a.constructor.PATH);
```

Note that the `var a` will only be tied to anything useful if there are prototype functions on `System.startApp`, for example:

```js
var System = {
    startApp:function(package) {
        System.startApp.PACKAGE = package;
        System.startApp.PATH = "@APP:/" + package;
    },
};
System.startApp.prototype.doSomething = () => {
  console.log('doing something');
};

var a = new System.startApp("Mr. T.");
console.log(a.constructor.PACKAGE + ", " + a.constructor.PATH);
a.doSomething();
```

If you don't have that, it doesn't make sense for `startApp` to be called as a constructor, nor does it make much sense to assign properties to the function.

If you want every instance to have separate properties, then assign to properties of `this`:

```js
var System = {
    startApp:function(package) {
        this.PACKAGE = package;
        this.PATH = "@APP:/" + package;
    },
};
var a = new System.startApp("Mr. T.");
console.log(a.PACKAGE + ", " + a.PATH);
```

Comment: Do you have any method that excludes the ```.constructor``` part

Comment: Like the answer says: `check the properties of the constructor (either a.constructor or System.startApp):` So if you don't want to use `a.constructor`, use `System.startApp` (though unless there's a good reason for all this, better to change the `System` code entirely, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense)

Comment: Yes, but, i need to make them variable because i intend to use various times

Comment: You mean, you want multiple calls of `startApp` to have different associated `PACKAGE` and `PATH` properties, or what?

Comment: Exactly this, sorry, i have bad english

Comment: Ok, editing... you should say that in your question

Comment: The use of ```this``` shows undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191054/discussion-between-eduardo-procopio-gomez-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 0):

The issue pertains to object binding. You are setting the variables to the property of the object itself, and not the instance of the object.

Comment: and how i make this?